# Durandal open dialog without viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, durandal, durandal-2.0

I want to open a custom Dialog in Durandal without a viewmodal. I want to set the path to the .html and want to do the js-stuff in the file, that opened the dialog. When a function has an Input by a click-event it works:

```
editActivePeriod = function(period){
            period.viewUrl = 'views/editActivePeriod';
            app.showDialog(period);
        },
```

But my funtion has no input, so how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "...my function has no input,..."?

Comment: `editActivePeriod = function(period){
            period.viewUrl = 'views/editActivePeriod';
            app.showDialog(period);
        }` This function has an input and can open a modal, this one hasn't an input: `addActivePeriod = function () {
            app.showDialog(open the modal);
        },`